# BigQuery from Python script access problems

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following bug for User:

> Access Denied: Project [project]: User does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission in project [project]

I want to share for User **only one Dataset**.

So what I have done:

1. In IAM this User has Roles: BigQuery Job User, Create Service Accounts, Service Account Key Admin;
2. In Service account this User has Roles: Create Service Accounts, Editor, Service Account Key Admin;
3. On Dataset Sharing this User has Roles: BigQuery User, BigQuery Data Viewer, BigQuery Data Editor

This User generated a Key-file and use it in Python in

```
service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("key.json")
```

BUT User get an error: does not have bigquery.jobs.create permission

I don't know what I shoul make else to grant him permissions.
I'm afraid that I can open him all the Project datasets.

---

Here are all permissions for User@gmail.com (with service acount loginSA):
Report on query results:
Role grant

```
| projects/[myproject]/datasets/shared_reports/tables/table1 |  BigQuery Data Viewer    |
| projects/[myproject]/datasets/shared_reports/tables/table2 |  BigQuery Data Viewer    |
| projects/[myproject]/datasets/shared_reports/tables/table3 |  BigQuery Admin   |
| projects/[myproject]/datasets/shared_reports/tables/table3 |  BigQuery Data Editor    |
| projects/[myproject]/datasets/shared_reports/tables/table3 |  BigQuery Data Viewer    |
|   //iam.googleapis.com/projects/[myproject]/serviceAccounts/loginSA@[myproject].iam.gserviceaccount.com | Editor  |
| projects/[myproject]/datasets/shared_reports |    BigQuery Data Editor    |
| projects/[myproject]/datasets/shared_reports |    BigQuery Data Viewer    |
| projects/[myproject]/datasets/shared_reports |    BigQuery User   |
| [Project Name] |  BigQuery Job User   |
| [Project Name] |  Create Service Accounts |
| [Project Name] |  Service Account Key Admin |
```